# Why is TypeScript showing an error even with a condition?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm encountering an issue with TypeScript (TS2531) and its non-null type checking. I have the following code:

```
if (this.formGroup.get('inseeActivityCode') !== null) {
    mergedCompanyActivity.inseeActivityCode = this.formGroup.get('inseeActivityCode').value; // => TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
}
```

In this code, I'm explicitly checking if `inseeActivityCodeControl` is not null before accessing its value property. However, TypeScript still gives me the error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null' on the `inseeActivityCodeControl.value` part.

My understanding was that the condition would prevent this error from occurring. Can someone explain why TypeScript is still raising this error and how to resolve it without using the `!` assertion operator?
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because static code analysis doesn't go that far. For TS  the result of the `get()` is `sometype | null` and that's what's used throughout static code analysis. What you can do is assign the result of `get(...)` to a variable and check that variable against `null`

```
let iac = this.formGroup.get('inseeActivityCode');
if (iac !== null) {
  mergedCompanyActivity.inseeActivityCode = iac.value; 
}
```

**Edit**

Why does this work for the assignment but not the function call? Because there is no guarantee whatsoever, that two subsequent calls to the same method will return the same (or even a valid) value. It will probably in your case, but the compiler can't know that. It can only check the method's signature, which will be `function get(key: string) : sometype | null`

Imagine a function like

```
function foo() {
  return Date.now() % 2 === 0 ? "foo" : null;
}
```

If you now do

```
if (foo() !== null) { 
  let l = foo().length;
}
```

there is no guarantee whatsoever, that the second call of `foo()` will return a string. It might as well return `null`.

But on the other hand if you do

```
let f = foo();
if (f !== null) {
  let l = f.length;
}
let l2 = f.length; //will still throw an error here!
```

once the compiler analizes the `!== null` check it can be sure, that within the condition's body `f` is not null. Ie, the type of `f` has been narrowed down from `string | null` to `string`. And that cannot change, unless you reassign the value of `f`.

Or course if you access `f` outside the condition's body, there is still no guarantee, that `f` is not null, thus the compiler will throw an error on the assignment of `l2`